# Need to schedule (cron job) a Java app which is deployed in three instances from pipeline

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, design-patterns, cron

We have a Java app that will be deployed into three instances at the same time due to the pipeline policy, which does the MongoDB clean-up (deletion of unnecessary records). The Java app will use the cron expression to start its cleanup activity, since all three instances will have the same cron expression, the 3 apps will start to do the cleanup in parallel which is going to create a mess. So, I want to avoid all three instances starting at once instead any one instance should be eligible for cleanup.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Look at a solution like Quartz

Comment: You can't avoid that the jobs start at the same time when you use the same cron expression but you can use your mongoDB database to create a lock. The first instance will get the lock, proceeds and release the lock when finished. The other instances stop processing when not able to get te lock.

Comment: I cannot lock the DB because there is another microservice that actually uses the DB for its CURD operations.